# How to extract latitude and longitude from the response dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios

My response is

```
{"Vehicle":[
   {"ID":"11","latitude":"8.513333","longitude":"76.969722"},
   {"ID":"12","latitude":"8.565","longitude":"76.879722"},
   {"ID":"15","latitude":"8.565","longitude":"76.879444"},
   {"ID":"16","latitude":"8.543333","longitude":"76.913333"}
]}
```

How to extract the latitude and longitude of each id separately ? 
I want to find the nearest coordinate.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

{

```
if ([RecievedDataBus length]>0)
{
    NSString*mystring=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:RecievedDataBus encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",mystring);
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:RecievedDataBus options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    NSDictionary*Dictionary=[result objectForKey:@"vehicle_id"];
    FinalbusIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[Dictionary valueForKey:@"ID"]];

    for (int i=0;i<[FinalbusIDs count]; i++)
    {.....}}
```

then again for another request the control comes again to this didfinishloading.....for the second request.for the first time its working properly.but for second tim the CFString has both the previous CFString and the new one.

Comment: actually am receiving one one response dictionary in the same class and this one is the second response for another request.so the CFString is having both the data together and when am extracting its showing <Nil>objects in the dictionary after JSON serialisation.

Comment: here is my code....what should i do to get the latitude and longitude for the next request response.

Comment: @JubinCVarughese You need to learn [basics of JSON parsing](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).

Answer (score 1):

First store your data in dictionary (dic) and then do it.

```
double latitue   = [[[dic valueForKeyPath:@"Vehicle.latitude"] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]];
double longitude = [[[dic valueForKeyPath:@"Vehicle.longitude"] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]];

NSLog(@"Latitude %g",latitue);
NSLog(@"Longitude %g",longitude);
```

// do same for more index